# WARNING: Variable MAIN already exists on file WORK.TEST

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to pull some data. The new table is supposed to contain 36 variables, but only includes 31, where 5 variables get this warning:

> WARNING: Variable Main_ind already exists on file WORK.TEST.

It is just a basic select statement and inner joins between 5 tables - none of them contain the same variable name.

```
create table test as
select t1.a,
   t1.b,
   t1.c,
   t1.main
   ...
   ...  
   ...
from ....
inner join...
on...
```

I need to have 36 variables, where only 31 are printed
  - 5 variables get the mentioned warning, and are for some reason, not printed

Comment: Have you tried to ask Google? For example : http://support.sas.com/kb/9/963.html

Comment: yes I have. and it offers a solution to a different problem. in my case, there are no 2 similar variables...

Comment: @Eyal, if you are **not** using `*` in your `select` statement, then you might find you have `Main_ind` mentioned twice in your `select` statement. Make sure you only refer to each variable once in the `select`statement even if it is coming from a different table.

Comment: thank you, but I know. I have 36 totally distinct variables from 5 tables.

Comment: If you perform a find using your editor for one of the problem columns and it only appears once after you repeat the find then try commenting out the columns you are selecting and then introduce them one at a time and try running the code until you get the same warning. Further it would probably be helpful if you edit your original question and share **all** of the SQL code.

Comment: @EyalMarom it say's here that "where like-named columns exist in multiple tables listed on the FROM clause" that to me does not sound like "there are no 2 similar variables".

Comment: That type of error could pop up if you are missing a comma somewhere. It would be helpful to see all of the query.